# HTML Table - Replace values in columns if the column contains a specific symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to write a JavaScript/JQuery function that replaces integer values in a column with a - if the column contains the asterisk (*) symbol.

Have been trying to look for suitable examples of replacing values in tables but so have only found functions that return true or false if column contains a value.

I need to check all columns in the table and replace where a column has one or more occurences of the * symbol only if the field contains an integer value.

Have provided an example table which includes the * symbol as reference:

```html
<table class="users">
                        <tbody><tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <th scope="col">May17 - Apr18</th>
                                <th>Jun17 - May18</th>
                                <th>Jul17 - Jun18</th>
                                <th>Aug17 - Jul18</th>
                                <th>Sep17 - Aug18</th>
                                <th>Oct17 - Sep18</th>
                                <th>Nov17 - Oct18</th>
                                <th>Dec17 - Nov18</th>
                                <th>Jan18 - Dec18</th>
                                <th>Feb18 - Jan19</th>
                                <th>Mar18 - Feb19</th>
                                <th>Apr18 - Mar19</th>
                                <th>May18 - Apr19</th>
                                <th>Jun18 - May19</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Opiate</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>9</td>
                                <td>9</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Non-opiate only</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Non-opiate and Alcohol</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Alcohol only</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>17</td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                        </tr>

                </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your HTML Table?  Is there any reason you can't use data-attributes in the HTML Tag, because that would be optimal. You've also posted the original function you are trying to modify, can you update that with what you are currently trying?

Comment: don't tend to use data-attributes, the functionality I need is situational in that I only need it to apply to logged out users, have also provide one of the tables which I need this to be applied to

Comment: OK, also now that I read it, it's a bit confusing in your explanation of what is being replaced.  I'm thinking, from the example - may17th get changed to '-' and that's it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've started working on a solution for you, let me know if I'm on the right track and I'll complete it. This is just a proof of concept, where I'm turning the data to alter 'red'.

First the Jquery to select the column:

```
/* Set all the cells in columns with * in the heading to red */
columnTh = $("table td:contains('*')"); 
// Get the index & increment by 1 to match nth-child indexing
columnIndex = columnTh.index() + 1; 
// Set all the elements with that index in a tr red
$('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').css("color", "#F00");
```

Working on this in a jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/2xU8t/549/

Am I getting close to the right idea?  Let me know and I'll continue.

---

Updated Answer - extending on what i posted earlier and updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tremor/2xU8t/603/

```
var parentTH = []; 
var cells = $("td:contains('*')");

cells.each(function (key, value) {
 if (value.textContent == "*") {
  var $th = $(value).closest('table').find('th').eq(value.cellIndex); 
  if (!parentTH.includes($th[0])) {
   parentTH.push($th[0]);
  } 
 }
});

for (var i = 0; i < parentTH.length; i++) {
 columnTh = $(parentTH[i]); 
 columnIndex = columnTh.index() + 1; 
 $('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').each(function (key, value) {
   var thisKey = key + 1;
   if (!isNaN(value.innerText)) {
     value.innerHTML = "-";
     $(value).css("color", "#F00");
   }
 });
};
```

Comment: yes this is very much on the right track, the selector needs to only identify the numeric values and the * where found needs to remain

Comment: @CryoFusion87 - I've updated my fiddle based on original concept, i've replaced Integers where appropriate with "-" and also colored them red for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply attempting to replace the *, use the ':contains()' selector to choose those DOM elements, and then update the text as needed:

```js
$(function(){
  $("td:contains(*)").text("------");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="users">
                        <tbody><tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <th scope="col">May17 - Apr18</th>
                                <th>Jun17 - May18</th>
                                <th>Jul17 - Jun18</th>
                                <th>Aug17 - Jul18</th>
                                <th>Sep17 - Aug18</th>
                                <th>Oct17 - Sep18</th>
                                <th>Nov17 - Oct18</th>
                                <th>Dec17 - Nov18</th>
                                <th>Jan18 - Dec18</th>
                                <th>Feb18 - Jan19</th>
                                <th>Mar18 - Feb19</th>
                                <th>Apr18 - Mar19</th>
                                <th>May18 - Apr19</th>
                                <th>Jun18 - May19</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Opiate</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>9</td>
                                <td>9</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Non-opiate only</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Non-opiate and Alcohol</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                                <td>*</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Alcohol only</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>17</td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                                <td>24</td>
                        </tr>

                </tbody></table>
```

So I'd oversimplified. Rather than simply blanking those fields, you want to blank those columns. Will the first row always be a head? If so, I might move that into a thead element, and keep the tbody for the data you will be manipulating.

The reason I consider that is, it makes the code a bit easier. First, you want to go through all rows, and check each td for the asterisk. If found, push that td's index onto an array containing all columns to be hidden. When that has been done, you will have an array containing all columns with an *, regardless of what row it lives in. Then, re-iterate over each row, setting its :nth-child td to your desired character. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  // This will be used to contain column indexes
  let columnIndexesToHide = [];
  // Iterate over each row...
  $("tr").each(function() {
    let row = $(this);
    // ...find each td within that row...
    row.find("td").each(function() {
      let cell = $(this);
      // ... and check if it contains an asterisk.
      if (cell.text().indexOf("*") !== -1) {
        // Additionally, have we already stored this column?
        if (!columnIndexesToHide.includes(cell.index())) {
          columnIndexesToHide.push(cell.index());
        }
      }
    })
  })
  /**
   * At this point, we have a list of columns that need to
   *  be hidden.
   * Using that column value, we can tell each row to hide
   *  the relevant column. By moving the header into the
   *  thead el, we can simply use tbody. Otherwise, we have
   *  to do some gymnastics to preserve the first tr but 
   *  replace the others. Assuming you don't also have a 
   *  tfoot row. or whatever.
   **/
  $.each(columnIndexesToHide, function(index, value) {
    let col = value + 1;
    $("tbody tr :nth-child(" + col + ")").each(function() {
      let cell = $(this);
      if (cell.text().indexOf("*") == -1 ) cell.text("--");
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="users">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <th scope="col">May17 - Apr18</th>
      <th>Jun17 - May18</th>
      <th>Jul17 - Jun18</th>
      <th>Aug17 - Jul18</th>
      <th>Sep17 - Aug18</th>
      <th>Oct17 - Sep18</th>
      <th>Nov17 - Oct18</th>
      <th>Dec17 - Nov18</th>
      <th>Jan18 - Dec18</th>
      <th>Feb18 - Jan19</th>
      <th>Mar18 - Feb19</th>
      <th>Apr18 - Mar19</th>
      <th>May18 - Apr19</th>
      <th>Jun18 - May19</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Opiate</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non-opiate only</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non-opiate and Alcohol</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alcohol only</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think you fully read the question, he's attempting to replace any integers, in a column, with a '-', if and only if the column also contains at '*'  - atleast that's how the question reads to me.  I agree in the contains method, in order to select a columnIndex to operate on.

Comment: not what I'm going for what I want to replace is the integer values in the column where a * exists in that column

Comment: Try that second one, @CryoFusion87 -- i think it may be more in tune with what you're looking for.